# How ASP.NET Core MVC + Entity Framework Core get the id of a newly added object

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have the following action method to add a parent (`Submission`) and child (`SubmissionQuestionSubmission`) objects:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Submission,SubmissionQuestionSubmission")] SubmissionCreate sc )
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var newsubmission  =  _context.Submission.Add(sc.Submission);
        sc.Submission.Created = DateTime.Now;
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        foreach (var v in sc.SubmissionQuestionSubmission)
        {
            v.SubmissionId = sc.Submission.Id;//i though this will be null..
            _context.SubmissionQuestionSubmission.Add(v);
        }

        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}
```

At first I thought that the code will not work as the `sc.Submission.Id` parent foreign key will be null, since I have just added the submission object. but my code work well, so how did the ASP.NET Core MVC and Entity Framework Core retrieved the `Id` of the newly added object? Will it automatically do a round trip to the database?

Here are my model classes:

```
public partial class Submission
{
    public Submission()
    {
        SubmissionQuestionSubmission = new HashSet<SubmissionQuestionSubmission>();
    }

    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Created { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<SubmissionQuestionSubmission> SubmissionQuestionSubmission { get; set; }
}

public partial class SubmissionQuestionSubmission
{
        public int SubmissionQuestionId { get; set; }
        public long SubmissionId { get; set; }
        public bool? Answer { get; set; }

        public virtual Submission Submission { get; set; }
        public virtual SubmissionQuestion SubmissionQuestion { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: No need to do this. You can (and should) add the `SubmissionQuestionSubmission` to `Submission.SubmissionQuestionSubmission` and call `SaveChanges`  once.

Comment: @GertArnold can you advice more on your reply please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `SaveChanges()` is called it will automatically update the `Id` field for the new saved entity. As an example, EF might generate queries as follow when saving a new entity:

```
SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ
BEGIN

INSERT INTO `Author` (`Name`)
VALUES ('test');

SELECT `Id`
FROM `Author`
WHERE ROW_COUNT() = 1
 AND `Id`=LAST_INSERT_ID()

COMMIT
```

As you see it will run the `INSERT INTO` query followed by a `SELECT` query to get the `Id` of the new inserted row, which will be saved in the `Id` property.

Comment: thanks for your useful reply,, but i have a question can this`LAST_INSERT_ID()` cause the EF to retrieve the wrong Id in a system which has a high number of users executing the same code?

Comment: @testtest No, `LAST_INSERT_ID()` works per connection and EF will use a transaction to insert the new entity and read the new created ID.